# autoscroll is not working on Tree Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, scroll, extjs5, treepanel

I try to add scrollbar to the tree panel but even if I add the `autoscroll : true` it doesn't scroll.

here is the panel :

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
                                title: 'asdasd',
                                autoscroll:true,
                                store: store,
                                rootVisible: false,
                            });
```

And also, i show this panel on new window.

Comment: yes i did, it didnt work either.@Alexander

Comment: Share you entire config including the window please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ExtJS5 you should use `scrollable` config for that purpose. (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-scrollable)

Here is the fiddle I've made to try it: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jd4

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {

root: {
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
        text: "Grand Parent",
        checked: false,
        isSelected: false,
        id: '1',
        children: [{
            text: 'Child Node',
            checked: false,
            IsSelected: false,
            id: '1.1',
            children: [{
                text: "Grand Child One",
                expanded: true,
                checked: false,
                isSelected: false,
                id: '1.1.1',
            }, {

                text: "Grand Child Two",
                expanded: true,
                checked: false,
                isSelected: false,
                id: '1.1.2',
            }, {

                text: "Grand Child Three",
                expanded: true,
                checked: false,
                isSelected: false,
                id: '1.1.3',
            }]
        }, {

            text: 'Child Two',
            checked: false,
            isSelected: false,
            id: '1.2',
            children: [{
                text: "Grand Child Four",
                expanded: true,
                checked: false,
                isSelected: false,
                id: '1.2.1',
            }]
        }]

    }]
}
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
title: 'Example Tree',
width: 200,
height: 450,
store: store,
rootVisible: false,
multiSelect: true,
scrollable: true,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

});
```